# Rails has_one nested attribute, Association Mismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

Here is how the app looks like:

Model

```
Class Location 
belongs_to :answer
attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :answer_id
end


Class Answer
attr_accessible :location
has_one :location
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

Controller

```
def answer
   @answer = Answer.new
   @location = @answer.build_location  
end
```

View

```
<%= f.fields_for :location do |locator| %>
    <%= locator.hidden_field :longitude, class:'longitude' %>
    <%= locator.hidden_field :latitude, class:'latitude' %>
 <% end %>
```

The Hash sent (visible in the log):

```
"answer"=>{"location"=>{"longitude"=>"2.3422566", "latitude"=>"48.8198344"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
```

The error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Can Someone help me find out the problem?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

"answer"=>{"location_attributes"=>{"longitude"=>"2.3422566", "latitude"=>"48.8198344"}, "commit"=>"Send"}